# Copy and paste from excel cell creates new line... how can I stop this?

Tags: excel, copy, line-breaks, paste

So if I have a cell that contains abc and I copy the entire cell into say SQL server it always includes another line ie:

```
'abc
'
```

Instead of

```
'abc'
```

If I double click in the cell and highlight the data it will appear correctly.  All this time I have just been putting up with this annoyance but surely there has got to be a way I can click just the cell, and copy the entire cell without the line break???  I have googled too much over this and could not find anything other than how to add/remove page breaks which does not help.

I should add that the '' marks are already in SQL so when I paste a cell between the '' it puts the last ' on the new line

Comment: I edited to make more sense as I could see the confusion. the cell contains ABC.... not 'ABC' the hash marks are in SQL and I just want to paste between them without the line break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Excel adds line break when copying a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695836/ms-excel-adds-line-break-when-copying-a-cell)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use regular expression to replace 'space' with 'no space'

Using Qt:  replace(QRegExp("\s"), "");