# How to copy multiple rows in Excel without a line break

Tags: excel, vba, copy, line, break

I'm trying to figure out how to copy multiple rows without **a line break** from Excel to a text file via VBA. I found a code on this website from Peter ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695836/ms-excel-adds-line-break-when-copying-a-cell)) that helped me a lot but it only works for me when copying one cell (F1 for example):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

DataObj.SetText ActiveSheet.Range("F1")
DataObj.PutInClipboard


End Sub
```

I tried to modify the code above for copying multiple cells as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

DataObj.SetText ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F10")
DataObj.PutInClipboard


End Sub
```

But I'm getting an error - Run-time error '13': type mismatch.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F10") is a range not text, hence the error.  Thus you need to convert the range to text before assigning to DataObj.SetText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fails because it expects information to be in Text format. You can modify `.SetText` line as below.

`DataObj.SetText Join(Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F10").Value))`

In principle, we are using `Transpose` to build a horizontal array and the use `Join` to build one string.

**Note:** In your code, you have not used `.value` which still works as it is the implicitly used property. It is better to define the property explicitly i.e.

`DataObj.SetText ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value`